# Api Blueprint With Faker Data

Tags: apiblueprint

I am using Faker to seed my data for my mostly read-only REST API. I've looked into API Blueprint for testing the API, however I am confused on how this can be accomplished with inconsistent faker data.  It seems you have to define the exact json output for a specified query.

Any tips on working with API Blueprint and Faker?

Answer (score 4):

API blueprint and Dredd for testing isn't possible use Faker directly.

For describe data you can use [JSON schema](http://json-schema.org/examples.html) and define type what you are using.

You can use [dredd hooks](https://dredd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/hooks/) for pairing incoming data with generated payloads. Dredd have to control structure not values.

If you have some blueprint example and code this will helps.